# How to construct C struct in Go side?

Tags: go, cgo

I need to call a C function which needs a pointer of struct as argument.
Here's the C code:

```
struct Position
{
    uint64_t index;
    uint64_t offset;
};

int read(const char* filename, const Position* pos, const char** data)
```

So in Go code, I think I have to malloc memory to construct a Position object and pass its pointer to C function. Maybe I also need to free memory. It seems like what C.CString() did. So how can I do that? Is there any code example? THX.

Answer (score -2):

How call c from golang is clear by the generated stub. use `go build -work src/main.go` to generate the stub and get the working directory. find the function prototype in `_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go` file.
i.e. I can get the following generated go stub:

```
type _Ctype_Position _Ctype_struct__Position
type _Ctype_struct__Position struct {
//line :1                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    index   _Ctype_int
//line :1                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    offset  _Ctype_int
//line :1                                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
func _Cfunc_read(p0 *_Ctype_char, p1 *_Ctype_struct__Position, p2 **_Ctype_char) (r1 _Ctype_int)
```

if i have the c header file like this:

```
typedef struct _Position
{
  int index;
  int offset;
}Position;

extern int read(const char* filename, const Position* pos, const char** data);
```

BTW you need reference the c function in go source to make a dependency for `go build` to generate the referenced function stub.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to allocate a new `struct Position` value that can be used with the imported `read` function.

Comment: that's true. You need know basics cgo inter-calls. Then my answer will fill the gap of alloc and pass struct.